# jQuery can't access append element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, append

I have this inside a function:

```
$('#users').append($("<div id='usuarios'>").text(mensaje[1][i]));
```

I want to create an onclick event for this new `<div>`. How can I achieve this?
I'm trying it like this outside the function:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#usuarios').click(function() {
        alert("click");
    });
});
```

But it doesn't work.

Answer (score 7):

For jQuery 1.7+ you can attach an event handler to a parent element using [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('body').on('click', '#usuarios', function() {
     alert("click");
  });
});
```

or Even better:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#users').on('click', '#usuarios', function() {
     alert("click");
  });
});
```

Comment: $('body').live('click', '#usuarios', function() {})can also be used but as of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is deprecated.

Comment: Even better would be `$('#users').on('click', '#usuarios', function() {`.  You want the event handler on the closest parent that is not dynamic (better performance when lots of event handlers).  That's why `.live()` was deprecated because it put all handlers on the `document`.

Comment: @jfriend00 Among other nuisances, such as being *magic*, a wasted selector lookup, etc.

Answer (score 5):

You could do it inline (by chaining `.append` after `.text`), because that's just how jQuery's API works, but you could also put it in a variable, which looks better:

```
var usarios = $("<div id='usuarios'>").text(mensaje[1][i]);

usarios.click(function() {
    alert('click');
});

$('#users').append(usarios);
```

Comment: @ATOzTOA: Dynamically added to the DOM by the `$('#users').append` line, yes. That's... the point?

Comment: @ATOzTOA: No. Have you checked whether this doesn't work? ([Yes, it works.](http://jsfiddle.net/minitech/FP4Bn/))

Comment: I have been working with dynamic elements for a while, and `click()` never worked for a dynamic element.

Comment: @ATOzTOA: See parenthetical above.

Comment: @ATOzTOA: There's no difference between "dynamic" elements and "regular" elements, except when they're added. If you try to find an element in the document before it's actually in the document, of course it won't work. But if you're creating the element, you've got a reference to which you can add all the event listeners you like.

Comment: @ATOzTOA Your life was in danger before you knew this?

Comment: @alex This would have saved me a lot of time... and time is life :)

Comment: No. Time is money. Your money was saved. You probably don't even need that raise anymore.

Answer (score 3):

I've also faced this problem, if you put it inside the document.ready then it won't work. I've thought it was my syntax, but it's not.

Use the

```
$(document).on('click', "input[id^='radiobox']", function () { 
    alert('hihi'); 
});
```

then it works

Answer (score 1):

You are dynamically creating an element, so normal event handler won't work. You will have to use `on()` to attach event handler to your document.

```
$(document).on('click', "#usuarios", function() {
    // do your job here
});
```

Comment: I think this is the best answer of this specific question.

Answer (score 1):

Two ways

1.Jquery 1.7+

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('body').on('click', '#usuarios', function() {
     alert("click");
  });
});
```

2.Jquery<1.7

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('body').delegate('#usuarios','click', function() {
     alert("click");
  });
});
```